# Go GORM has many relationship. How to store the data to MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I am new to backend and as well as golang and gorm.

I'm learning backend by building simple api with has-many in go and gorm.

I'm try to create "Trip" table and "SingleTrip" table with foreign key of "TripId"

basically, a trip has a slice of singleTrip

Here the code,
I have two models which is

```
type Base struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID string `gorm:"primary_key;not_null" json:"id"`
}

type Trip struct {
    Base
    UserId     string        `gorm:"not_null" json:"user_id"`
    TripDetail []SingleTrip  `gorm:"foreignKey:Id;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;" json:"trip_detail"`

}

type SingleTrip struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id          string    `gorm:"primary_id" json:"id"`
    TripId      string    `gorm:"primary_key;not_null" json:"trip_id"`
    TripDate    string    `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"trip_date"`
    FromAddress string    `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"from_address"`
    ToAddress   string    `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"to_address"`
    Distance    float64   `gorm:"not_null;" json:"distance"`
    Reason      string    `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"reason"`
    Comments    string    `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"comments"`
    Receipts    string    `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"receipt"`
    Amount      float64   `gorm:"not_null;" json:"amount"`
    RoundTrip   string    `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"round_trip"`
}

func (trip *Trip) BeforeCreate(gorm *gorm.DB) error {
    tripId := uuid.New()
    trip.ID = tripId.String()
    return nil
}

func (singleTrip *SingleTrip) BeforeCreate(gorm *gorm.DB) error {
    id := uuid.New()
    singleTrip.Id = id.String()
    return nil

}
```

this is the request body i've try to save in mysql db

```
{
    "user_id": "d4be5cbc-4377-11ec-a108-2e7a8ebc414a",
    "trip_detail": [
        {
            "trip_date": "05/29/2021",
            "from_address":"from address field",
            "to_address": "to address field",
            "distance": 50.2,
            "reason": "dinner",
            "comments": "this is comments field",
            "receipt": "for lunch",
            "amount": 50.0,
            "round_trip": "round field"
        },
        {
            "trip_date": "07/29/2021",
            "from_address": "some address",
            "to_address": "Some to address",
            "distance": 50.2,
            "reason": "dinner",
            "comments": "this is  comment field",
            "receipt": "for meeting",
            "amount": 50.0,
            "round_trip": "round field"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is SaveTrip methods

```
func (trip *Trip) SaveTrip(db *gorm.DB) (*Trip, error) {
    err := db.Debug().Create(&trip).Error
    if err != nil {
        return &Trip{}, err
    }

    return trip, nil
}
```

controller
trip_controller.go

```
func (server *Server) CreateTrip(context *gin.Context) {
    errMessage := map[string]string{}
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(context.Request.Body)

    trip := models.Trip{}

    if err != nil {
        errMessage["Invalid Request"] = "Invalid Request"
        context.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusUnprocessableEntity,
            "error":  errMessage,
        })
        return
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &trip)
    if err != nil {
        errMessage["Unable to Unmarshall"] = "Unable to unmarshal"
        context.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusUnprocessableEntity,
            "error":  errMessage,
        })
        return
    }

    trip.Prepare()
    validatingErrMessage := map[string]string{}
    validatingErrMessage = trip.ValidatingTripData("create")

    if len(validatingErrMessage) > 0 {
        errMessage = validatingErrMessage
        context.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusUnprocessableEntity,
            "error":  errMessage,
        })
        return
    }

    createdTrip, err := trip.SaveTrip(server.DB)

    if err != nil {
        formattedError := utils.FormatError(err.Error())
        context.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusInternalServerError,
            "error":  err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "status":   http.StatusOK,
        "response": createdTrip,
    })

}
```

this is the response i'm getting from postman

```
{
    "response": {
        "ID": 0,
        "CreatedAt": "2021-11-18T00:08:55.357+05:30",
        "UpdatedAt": "2021-11-18T00:08:55.357+05:30",
        "DeletedAt": null,
        "id": "52a44faa-437a-4695-82c7-b45cdab9e6d1",
        "user_id": "d4be5cbc-4377-11ec-a108-2e7a8ebc414a",
        "trip_detail": [
            {
                "ID": 0,
                "CreatedAt": "2021-11-18T00:08:55.362+05:30",
                "UpdatedAt": "2021-11-18T00:08:55.362+05:30",
                "DeletedAt": null,
                "Id": "52a44faa-437a-4695-82c7-b45cdab9e6d1",
                "trip_date": "05/29/2021",
                "from_address": "some address",
                "to_address": "some - to address",
                "distance": 50.2,
                "reason": "dinner",
                "comments": "this is comments field",
                "receipt": "for lunch",
                "amount": 50,
                "round_trip": "round field"
            },
            {
                "ID": 0,
                "CreatedAt": "2021-11-18T00:08:55.362+05:30",
                "UpdatedAt": "2021-11-18T00:08:55.362+05:30",
                "DeletedAt": null,
                "Id": "52a44faa-437a-4695-82c7-b45cdab9e6d1",
                "trip_date": "07/29/2021",
                "from_address": "some address",
                "to_address": "Some to address",
                "distance": 50.2,
                "reason": "dinner",
                "comments": "this is  comment field",
                "receipt": "for meeting",
                "amount": 50,
                "round_trip": "round field"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 200
}
```

but data's not store in DB

when try to store data to db, i am getting below error

[image]

How to store the data in Db, or is there any other way to store the value?

I am using golang, gorm, gin framework.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry If I have bad grammar.

Change this line of code

```html
func (singleTrip *SingleTrip) BeforeCreate(gorm *gorm.DB) error {
    /*
        fmt.Println(singleTrip.Id) // this value will be Trip (parent) ID
    */

    id := uuid.New()

    // WRONG
    // singleTrip.Id = id.String()

    /* 
        Maybe This is what you want
        TripId is the primary Key
        not Id (from how you define the model tag)
    */
    singleTrip.TripId = id.String() 
    return nil
}
```

`Id` in `SingleTrip` (in this case, is a foreign key, not the primary key) must not be overwritten with `BeforeCreate` because gorm relation already handles the Id value to be `ID` from `Trip` (parent). You can try to log the value if you want.

This will cause an error in MySQL itself because in the transaction the new id is not recorded in the parent (`Trip`) Primary Key.

And a little suggestion, Be Wise to choose the foreign key name, like `trip_id` is good for `Trip` x `SingleTrip` foreign key instead of `Id`.  It is confusing to understand the model at first.

Full Code:

```html
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
)

var DB *gorm.DB

func main() {
    databaseConfig := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?multiStatements=true&parseTime=true", "root", "", "127.0.0.1", "3306", "tester")

    DB, _ = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(databaseConfig), &gorm.Config{
        Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
    })
    sqlDB, _ := DB.DB()
    defer sqlDB.Close()

    DB.AutoMigrate(&Trip{}, &SingleTrip{})

    router := gin.Default()

    router.POST("/", CreateTrip)

    router.Run(":8080")
}

type Base struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID string `gorm:"primary_key;not_null" json:"id"`
}

type Trip struct {
    // Base
    gorm.Model
    ID         string       `gorm:"size:255;primary_key;not_null" json:"id"`
    UserId     string       `gorm:"not_null" json:"user_id"`
    TripDetail []SingleTrip `gorm:"foreignKey:Id;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;" json:"trip_detail"`
}

type SingleTrip struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id          string  `gorm:"size:255;primary_id" json:"id"`
    TripId      string  `gorm:"primary_key;not_null" json:"trip_id"`
    TripDate    string  `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"trip_date"`
    FromAddress string  `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"from_address"`
    ToAddress   string  `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"to_address"`
    Distance    float64 `gorm:"not_null;" json:"distance"`
    Reason      string  `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"reason"`
    Comments    string  `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"comments"`
    Receipts    string  `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"receipt"`
    Amount      float64 `gorm:"not_null;" json:"amount"`
    RoundTrip   string  `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"round_trip"`
}

func (trip *Trip) BeforeCreate(gorm *gorm.DB) error {
    tripId := uuid.New()
    trip.ID = tripId.String()
    return nil
}

func (singleTrip *SingleTrip) BeforeCreate(gorm *gorm.DB) error {
    /*
        fmt.Println(singleTrip.Id) // this value will be Trip (parent) ID
    */

    id := uuid.New()

    // WRONG
    // singleTrip.Id = id.String()

    /* 
        Maybe This is what you want
        TripId is the primary Key
        not Id (from how you define the model tag)
    */
    singleTrip.TripId = id.String() 
    return nil
}

func (trip *Trip) SaveTrip(db *gorm.DB) (*Trip, error) {
    err := db.Debug().Create(&trip).Error
    if err != nil {
        return &Trip{}, err
    }

    return trip, nil
}

// =======================================================
func CreateTrip(context *gin.Context) {
    errMessage := map[string]string{}
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(context.Request.Body)

    trip := Trip{}

    if err != nil {
        errMessage["Invalid Request"] = "Invalid Request"
        context.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusUnprocessableEntity,
            "error":  errMessage,
        })
        return
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &trip)
    if err != nil {
        errMessage["Unable to Unmarshall"] = "Unable to unmarshal"
        context.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusUnprocessableEntity,
            "error":  errMessage,
        })
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("Trip: %+v", trip)
    // fmt.Printf("Trip: %+v", trip.TripDetail[0].ID)
    // fmt.Printf("Trip: %+v", trip.TripDetail[0].Id)

    // trip.Prepare()
    // validatingErrMessage := map[string]string{}
    // validatingErrMessage = trip.ValidatingTripData("create")

    // if len(validatingErrMessage) > 0 {
    //  errMessage = validatingErrMessage
    //  context.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
    //      "status": http.StatusUnprocessableEntity,
    //      "error":  errMessage,
    //  })
    //  return
    // }

    createdTrip, err := trip.SaveTrip(DB)

    if err != nil {
        // formattedError := utils.FormatError(err.Error())
        context.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusInternalServerError,
            "error":  err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "status":   http.StatusOK,
        "response": createdTrip,
    })

}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzUQn.png)